Can we solve all linear circuits using only KVL and constitutive relations?
Can We Solve for Node Voltages and Branch Currents in Any Linear Circuit Using Only KVL and Constitutive Relations?
In circuits with a single loop, it's trivial to solve using only Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL). However, I'm unsure if this method is applicable to all linear circuits. One restriction is that we cannot use any circuit simplification techniques; only KVL and constitutive relations are allowed.

Is it possible to solve for all node voltages and branch currents in any linear circuit without using Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL), solely relying on KVL equations and constitutive relations? If not, could you provide a rigorous proof or explanation?
Specifically, I have a circuit where it seems impossible to solve using only KVL equations but I would like to know a general proof if this is true.


I think your first example is incorrect, there are two knowns:

The voltage from the supply is \$ V1 = \text{5 Volts}\$
The value of R1 is 1000 Ohms

and there are three unknowns:

The current through the resistor \$i_{R1}\$
The voltage drop across the resistor \$V_{R1}\$
The current from the supply \$i_{V1}\$

There are three relevant equations that can be used to solve for the unknowns:

Constitutive relation for a resistor: \$ V_{R1} = R1 \times i_{R1}\$
Kirchhoff's voltage law: \$ -V1 + V_{R1} = 0\$
Kirchhoff's current law: \$ -i_{V1} + i_{R1} = 0 \$

If you only use the constitutive relation and Kirchoff's voltage law, you cannot say that \$ i_{V1} \$ equals \$ i_{R1} \$, and thus cannot solve for all the unknowns.

Interesting point. There is no explicit way to solve for the current of the source, but since there is one loop, I think we can conclude that the components are in series and the currents are the same. I'm wondering if this would be an issue in circuits with more than one loop.

@hana KCL is "at any instant in time, the sum of the currents entering a node equals the sum of the currents leaving the node". It can be derived from the conservation of charge equation. If you make the assumption that all the current flowing through the resistor comes from the voltage source, without intending to, you've just used KCL applied to a node between V1 and R1.

No, I don’t mean to use KCL directly, but the knowledge of KCL can be inferred from KVL in a single loop circuit because there’s no other path for the current to flow.

@hana To summarize your argument for the first example, you say that you solved for all voltages and currents in the circuit without using KCL. Instead, you used KVL, constitutive relations, and the assumption that the current through the resistor equals the current from the supply “because there’s no other path for the current to flow”. However, if you restate your assumption in a different manner, at the node between V1 and R1, the current flowing in equals the current flowing out (because there’s no other path for the current to flow). This is KCL, which you used to find the supply current.

@hana KCL cannot be inferred from KVL because the equations are independent. KCL is derived from conservation of charge, KVL is derived from Faraday’s law, assuming the time derivative of the magnetic field is negligible. These are two of the five Maxwell’s equations.

``For a network containing \$b\$ branches and \$n+1\$ nodes, there are \$n\$ independent KCL equations and \$b-n\$ KVL equations for a total of \$b\$. There are also \$b\$ V-i relationships, which combined with the other \$b\$ independent equations are sufficient to solve for the \$2 b\$ branch variables, \$b\$ currents and \$b\$ voltages.'' (Reference 1, page 104)
This statement is subject to the following restrictions:

A branch has a node on each end, so that \$n\ge1\$.
All branches are part of a closed path or loop, thus \$b\ge2\$.
All nodes in the graph are connected (there exists at least one path between any two nodes). This implies the circuit does not contain a transformer.
The circuit contains at least one independent source.

The proof of the above requires graph theory, which is not my strong suit. Under these conditions if you use the \$b-n\$ KVL equations, \$b\$ constitutive relations, but neglect the \$n\$ independent KCL equations, you don't have enough equations to solve for the \$b\$ currents and \$b\$ voltages. In other words:
Subject to the above conditions, there are no circuits that can be fully solved using KVL and constitutive relations only.
When a transformer is added, you have two separate sub-circuits coupled by the transformer. One sub-circuit must contain a independent source, but the transformer acts as the source for the other. This modifies the number of independent KCL and KVL equations, but I believe the above conclusion still holds.

Balabanian, N. and Bickart, T. ``Electrical Network Theory'', Robert E. Krieger Publishing Co., Malabar, Fl, 1985.


To determine the currents and voltages in an electrical network, the methods are those illustrated here, where the branch current and voltage vectors are indicated in bold and with a subscript b, while the matrices of the capacities, resistances and inductances are indicated with M and N, while the excitations vector is indicated with Ug and that of the initial conditions with Uinit. :beta_n is the connections matrix, alfa is the independent meshes matrix and beta_t is the independent cut sets matrix:


Hi. I'm aware of branch current analysis, but I'm wondering if it can be solved using only KVL equations and constitutive relations. Do you have a conclusion for that?

You can solve any circuit containing only voltage sources and linear resistors this way. This is effectively what you do when you use mesh analysis.
If the circuit contains current sources, you can't do it. To solve circuits with current sources, you must introduce the supermesh concept to the mesh analysis, producing the modified mesh analysis. However, the supermesh concept is essentially using KCL to describe the effect of the current source on the meshes it is part of, so by introducing the supermesh, you've added KCL to the inventory of concepts you've used to solve the circuit.

I have a circuit where it seems impossible to solve using only KVL equations but I would like to know a general proof if this is true

Your circuit can be solved using only KVL and Ohm's law, since it contains only voltage sources and linear resistors.
Taking the mesh currents as clockwise, I get these equations.
Mesh 1:
$$ V_1 - i_1R_1 - (i_1-i_2)R_2 = 0$$
Mesh 2:
$$ (i_1-i_2)R_2 + V_2 - i_2R_3 = 0$$
These are two linear equations with two unknowns, which you can solve easily.

I was considering mesh analysis as well, but mesh analysis is only applicable to planar circuits, so it is also not a general solution. You made a good point. So, KVL is not enough to solve for all voltages and currents in any circuit.

@hana, the mesh analysis fails on non-planar circuits because the fundamental meshes can't be identified, not because KCL needs to be introduced to solve them. Non-planar circuits with only voltage sources and linear resistors can still be solved using only KVL and Ohm's law, you just need more cleverness in finding a complete set of paths on which to apply KVL.

Okay, I think in the case of a supermesh, it can be considered as only using KVL equations because the KCL equation is actually derived/obtained from KVLs, so it's valid.

@hana, KCL is derived from conservation of charge. KVL is derived from the conservative property of the electric field (under the lumped circuit approximation). I don't believe one can be derived from the other, but if you have a source that explains how to do it, I'd be happy to learn.

For example, lets consider the supermesh of the circuit in the link below.
https://www.circuitbread.com/tutorials/special-case-of-kvl-supermesh-analysis
There is the equation, i1-i2=1 which is in KCL form but it's derived from two KVL equations of the two loops.

I have another question. If I add another restriction that there are no current sources (the circuit has only voltage sources, resistors, inductors, and capacitors), and you are given a set of all the KVL equations that can be made from the circuit and the constituent relations, can we be certain that we can solve for all voltages and currents from this?

@hana, yes, you can. Except in trivial circuits you will end up with more equations than unknowns, but some of the equations will not be linearly independent of the others. (You will have as many linearly independent equations as unknowns)
